# Ayuda con solucion Bag of Words con este error: ValueError: could not convert string to float:

Tags: python, machine-learning, anaconda, scikit-learn

Estoy empezando con Machine Learning y Python, y estoy usando un csv de tuits para hacer un analisis de sentimientos. En la columna target indica si los tuits son positivos o negativos. Este es mi codigo:

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
from sklearn.model_selection import train_test_split
from sklearn.feature_extraction.text import CountVectorizer
from sklearn import neighbors


    df = pd.read_csv('training.1600000.processed.noemoticon.csv',sep=',',engine='python')
    df.drop(['id'], 1, inplace=True)
    df.drop(['date'], 1, inplace=True)
    df.drop(['flag'], 1, inplace=True)
    df.drop(['user'], 1, inplace=True)

    x = np.array(df.drop(['target'],1))
    y = np.array(df['target'])

    x_train, x_test, y_train, y_test = train_test_split(x,y,test_size=0.2)

    clf = neighbors.KNeighborsClassifier()
    clf.fit(x_train, y_train)

    accuracy = clf.score(x_test, y_test)
    print(accuracy)
```

Y este es el error que me sale:

```
ValueError: could not convert string to float: 'im playing with a cat toy its radom but fun '
```

He visto que la solucion puede ser con Bag of words pero no se programarlo. Alguien sabría la solución? Muchas gracias

Comment: Hola, podrias poner una impresion de tu dataset? Es para ver todas las columnas y lo que contienen. Lo puedes hacer con la funcion head(). Como te digo, solo es para ver que tipo de datos guarda cada columna y cuales son las columnas totales del tu DataFrame. Gracias.